# Upload file on the FTP server via node js

Tags: node.js, ftp

I tried simple file upload on the FTP path via node js. For that I have installed ftp-client module.

**index.js**

```
    const ftpClient = require("ftp-client");

    // FTP Configuration
    const config = {
      host: '',
      port: 22,
      user: '',
      password: ''
    };

    const options = {
      logging: 'basic'
    };
    client = new ftpClient(config, options);

    client.connect(function (result) {
      client.upload(['./upload/test.txt'], '/opt/test_api', {
        baseDir: 'ogrds',
        overwrite: 'older'
      }, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
      })
    }
    );
```

When tried to execute by node index.js command, this is neither giving any results nor moved the file to the FTP server.

Comment: have you check for any errors it returned?

Comment: I haven't received any error code. The above part is my full code. Can you please help to modify?